# References for trees and digraphs formed from iterated functions

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, convergence-divergence, reference-request, trees

Given a function $f\colon \Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$.
Assume that for some index set $I$, there are $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\Bbb Z$ such that

> - $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{i\in I}(a_i+b_i\Bbb N_0)$ and $\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{i\in I}(c_i+d_i\Bbb N_0)$
> - For all $i\in I$, $n\in\Bbb N_0$, we have  $f(a_i+b_in)=c_i+d_in$

I am looking for references dealing with the properties of trees and digraphs formed from  $\{\,f^{\circ k}(x)\mid k\in\Bbb N_0\,\}$ for all $x\in \Bbb Z$.

For example:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}x,  & \text{subdoman:2, 4, 6, 8,...Subrange: 3, 6, 9, 12...} \\
\frac{-3}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{subdoman:1, 3, 5, 7,...Subrange:-1,-4,-7, -10...}\\
\frac{-1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}, & \text{subdoman:-1, -3, -5,...Subrange:1, 2, 3, ...}\\
\frac{1}{2}x, & \text{subdoman:-2, -4, -6,...Subrange:-1, -2, -3,...}
\end{cases}$$

Part of the tree is 
[image: 2]

And the digraph is 
[image]

I have read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) on iterated functions but it was more on fixed points. Appreciate any help.